# Extract .zip and then store contents in S3 with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Most questions regarding NodeJS, S3 and Zips are the opposite of what I would like to do. Upload a zip, and extract the files onto S3.

I have a quick app running on an Amazon EC2 instance, with Node.JS that accepts a file upload via a POST request. The aim is to upload a zip file full of images, extract them, and place each individual image on Amazon S3.

I am using express.js to accept the posted file, and I have been playing with AdmZip to read the uploaded zip file. With AdmZip, I can extract the zip file to the servers disk, then loop over each extracted image in a temporary directory and then send that to Amazon S3, but this seems very inefficient. 
I've read quite a bit about streaming files from S3 to Node and zipping it on the fly. I guess what I want to know is if this is possible in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't think you'll be able to extract the file "on" S3. You'll have to save the zip in /temp, extract and upload the indiviual files to s3.

Try some thing like this:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) { 

  myZip = req.files.myZipfile

  var zip = new require('node-zip')(myZip, {base64: false, checkCRC32: true});

  knox = require('knox');
  s3 = knox.createClient({"key": "", "secret": "", "bucket": ""})


  // You might need to try something like async here to throttle the putFile command
    for (var i = zip.files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 

        s3.putFile(zip.files[i], path.basename(zip.files[i]), function(err, res) {

        });
    };


});
```

Comment: I guess it would help if I read your _whole_ question. It looks like this is what you're already doing. have you tried looking at the docs for [pipe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options)

Comment: Thanks for the response mate. There doesn't seem to be a way to 'stream' the zip contents to S3. Your answer will be opening the zip, and reading the contents in ram, which is close to what I wanted.(faster than extracting to HDD and reading the files from the HDD)

So thanks for your response, you've pretty much answered my question!